# OpenGL application fades when texturing an object

Tags: opengl, graphics

I have an application that animates a person traversing the halls of a spaceship. I have also created an OpenGL DLL that the application links to. The purpose of this OpenGL DLL is to intercept specific calls, and then do something when these calls are intercepted.

The main call that i am concerned about intercepting is wglSwapBuffer ( i think thats the name ). In this call, i render a 3D object ( half sphere or half cylinder ) and specify texture coordinates for each vertex. I then capture the output of the framebuffer, and use it to texture the contents of the sphere using glCopyTexImage2D, or something like that.

After i do all that stuff, my dll the calls the real dll and the real swapbuffer method is called.

When i place my dll in the same folder as the application, I get what i expect, a dome with graphics textured onto it. What i did not expect is that the screen fades constently. What i mean by that is that everything looks the way its supposed to, and then over a second interval, the screen will fade to be completly black, and then it will come back to being normal. This repeats with an average frequency of about a second, sometimes its faster, sometimes its slower, it seems to depend on hard the processor is working.

Any ideas?

Comment: So what i do is i clear the screen, resize it, render an object and texture on to. if i dont clear the screen or resize or texture, the animation looks normal, but when i draw a 3d object in the swap buffer method without texturing it or anything, then the animation will still look normal, but somewhere in the center of the screen will appear an object that periodically fades.

Comment: Are you making sure to restore any GL state that you change in the DLL?

Comment: By state, do you mean disabling anything i enabled?

Comment: @Adham: No, more like grabbing whatever the app has set and that you modify, and restoring that after your code is done.

Comment: @Adham: Is there a reason why you don't render to a texture and use that to texture your dome, rather than messing around with intercepting SwapBuffer?

Comment: @Incredulous Monk: I am rendering to a texture, but i do it in the swapbuffer function. I make a call to glCopyTexSubImage ( i think ) and then render to texture.

Comment: @genpfault: You were right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was something to with blending. So in the swapbuffer method, i disabled blending, did my stuff, and then re-enabled blending, and now it works.